# How can I Trim the leading comma in my string

Tags: c#, .net, string, trim

I have a string that is like below.

```
,liger, unicorn, snipe
```

in other languages I'm familiar with I can just do a string.trim(",") but how can I do that in c#?

Thanks.

---

*There's been a lot of back and forth about the StartTrim function.  As several have pointed out, the StartTrim doesn't affect the primary variable.  However, given the construction of the data vs the question, I'm torn as to which answer to accept.  True the question only wants the first character trimmed off not the last (if anny), however, there would never be a "," at the end of the data.  So, with that said, I'm going to accept the first answer that that said to use StartTrim assigned to a new variable.*

Comment: Suggest adding tag ".net", since this isn't language-specific.

Comment: 85 views 10 answers and NO ONE thinks this question is worth a +1?

Comment: @Keng maybe because this kind of stuffs is kind of trivial for C# folks

Comment: isn't that the point?....everything is trivial to someone?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string sample = ",liger, unicorn, snipe";
sample = sample.TrimStart(','); // to remove just the first comma
```

Or perhaps:

```
sample = sample.Trim().TrimStart(','); // to remove any whitespace and then the first comma
```

Comment: Great answer ,  I also added in  TrimEnd as well     sample.Trim().TrimStart(',').TrimEnd(',');

Answer (score 21):

```
string s = ",liger, unicorn, snipe";
s.TrimStart(',');
```

Comment: Does that method _modifies_ the string? Shouldn't it be re-assigned back to s ala s = s.TrimStrat('/'); ?

Comment: No, strings are immutable. All manipulation functions return a new string with the changes applied.

Comment: Why is this a better answer than the selected?   Observations.   1. Is this user getting more points based on having more stackoverflow friend  AND/OR having over 15,000 points vs. the OP having under 2,000 points?

Answer (score 4):

.net strings can do Trim() and TrimStart().  Because it takes `params`, you can write:

```
",liger, unicorn, snipe".TrimStart(',')
```

and if you have more than one character to trim, you can write:

```
",liger, unicorn, snipe".TrimStart(",; ".ToCharArray())
```

Comment: wow.. that string to char array is one nice trick I've never saw before.

Comment: or `new [] { ',', ';', ' ' }`

Answer (score 3):

here is an easy way to not produce the leading comma to begin with:

```
string[] animals = { "liger", "unicorn", "snipe" };
string joined = string.Join(", ", animals);
```

Answer (score 3):

string.TrimStart(',') will remove the comma, however you will have trouble with a split operation due to the space after the comma. 
Best to join just on the single comma or use

> Split(", ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: You are the hero dude. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

",liger, unicorn, snipe".Trim(',') -> "liger, unicor, snipe"

Comment: The question asks to remove the 'leading comma', but Trim() "Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of specified characters from the current String object." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try string.Trim(',') and see if that does what you want.

Comment: The question asks to remove the 'leading comma', but Trim() "Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of specified characters from the current String object." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Note, the *original* string is left untouched, Trim will return you a new string:

```
string s1 = ",abc,d";
string s2 = s1.TrimStart(",".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine("s1 = {0}", s1);
Console.WriteLine("s2 = {0}", s2);
```

prints:

```
s1 = ,abc,d
s2 = abc,d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = ",liger, unicorn, snipe";
s = s.TrimStart(',');
```

It's important to assign the result of TrimStart to a variable. As it says on the [TrimStart page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx), "This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string...".

In .NET, strings don't change.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

,liger, unicorn, snipe".TrimStart(',');

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s.StartsWith(",")) {
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string t = ",liger, unicorn, snipe".TrimStart(new char[] {','});
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way as everywhere else: [string.trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    string s = ",liger, tiger";

    if (s.Substring(0, 1) == ",")
        s = s.Substring(1);
```

Comment: just fyi, you can do s.StartsWith(,  and not have to actually do all the substring just to get the first character.

Comment: Thanks ChanChan.  I often fall back on a small subset of .Net that I "expect" to be there, based on my previous experience with other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean trim all instances of "," in that string?

In which case, you can do:

```
s = s.Replace(",", "");
```

Comment: He just wants to remove the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Substring to ignore the first character (or assign it to another string);

```
 string o = ",liger, unicorn, snipe";
 string s = o.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx

```
        string animals = ",liger, unicorn, snipe";

        //trimmed will contain "liger, unicorn, snipe"
        string trimmed = word.Trim(',');
```